# how to yield 10000 lines of a file in python?

Tags: python, yield

I am reading a very big file, so I want to read 10000 once a time with python's lazy method:

```
def read_file():
    jd_records = []
    file_name = "test.csv"
    with open(file=file_name, mode='rt') as inf:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(inf.read(1024))
        inf.seek(0)
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=",")

        if has_header:
            next(incsv)

        while True:
            row = next(incsv)

            jd_records.append(row)

            line_num += 1

            if not line_num % 10000:
                yield jd_records
```

the problem with this method is that:
I can not yield the last date, such as I have 15555 lines, then the last 5555 will not be yield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code has several issues.

- There needs to be a `yield jd_records` outside the loop, to emit the remaining records. (This causes the problem mentioned in the question.)
- The `jd_records` list needs resetting, e.g. with `del jd_records[:]`, after the `yield` inside the loop. Without this, it will yield the same records many times.
- A bare `next(iterator)` will raise `StopIteration` after reading the last element. You need to wrap it in try/except or (better) use a `for` loop.

For example:

```
def read_file():
    jd_records = []
    file_name = "test.csv"
    with open(file=file_name, mode='rt') as inf:
        has_header = csv.Sniffer().has_header(inf.read(1024))
        inf.seek(0)
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter=",")

        if has_header:
            next(incsv)

        for row in incsv:
            jd_records.append(row)
            line_num += 1
            if not line_num % 10000:
                yield jd_records
                del jd_records[:]

        if jd_records:
            yield jd_records
```